# JS - Hide div if cookie exists

Tags: javascript, html, dom, cookies

Here, basically, I want to let a client show the div only once in 30 days. If no cookies are present the  div would be shown, and when clicked, the div would do something, irrelevant here, and then it would store some cookies, (e.g. client IP). If the cookies are present though the div would disappear. I have written some code here, check it out if you can, and help me solve the problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://l2.io/ip.js?var=myip"></script>
<script>
        var el = document.getElementsByClassName('popup');

if(!document.cookie) {
    el.style.display = 'block';
    setCookie("clientip", myip, 30);
} else {
    el.style.display = 'none';
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
</script>
```

How would I set a listener here, for "popup"?

BTW, the first script is something really cool I found for returning clients IP through JS.

Comment: It's a div, irrelevant here. @MitchKarajohn

Comment: @BillHicks, Not really! `getElementsByClassName` returns a nodelist...`array-like` Elements which does not have `style` property in it...

Comment: No, i thought you asked me what does that div do. Yes, I know it's a nodelist. Hmm, so how would I style it?

Comment: If there are many elements then `loop` or Just use index like `[0]`

Comment: @MitchKarajohn I found the solution, check my answer, and thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Do it with jQuery ;)

Set your cookie with `$.cookie("cookietitle", "cookievalue");` and to see if it is set and to hide the element, do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var CookieGet = $.cookie('yourcookie');
     if (CookieGet != null) {
          // Hide the element here.
          $('.yourelement').hide();
     }
 });
```

Comment: He doesn't really need to do something this simple with jQuery though, does he?

Comment: No, but it depends to his project. If he is already using jQuery, why not taking use of it? :)

Comment: @AleksandarSpasojević I found the solution, check my answer, and thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a listener for this. Simply have the `popup` element display as `none` by default, and put the code from your question, at the end of `<body>`.

Or have it load on [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded).

Also, yeah, as noted in the comment, you will have to change `getElementsByClassName` to something else, because right now `el` is not one element but a collection of elements. See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

If you know there is only one `popup` element you could do `document.querySelector('.popup');`

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some brainstorming, I realized i need to change my div from class to id, since it would be easier to deal with, and here is the rest:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://l2.io/ip.js?var=myip"></script>
<script>
    var el = document.getElementById('popup');
    el.addEventListener('click', showhide);

    if(!document.cookie) {
        console.log("No cookie");
        setCookie("clientip", myip, 30);
        function showhide() {
            el.style.display = 'none';
            console.log("Cookie is stored");
        }
    } else {
        el.style.display = 'none';
        console.log("We have your cookies");
    }

    function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
    }
</script>
```